# Django uploads, video, images, pdf etc

Tags: python, html, django

Please I really need a solution, I’ve been trying to figure out on how I could create a model field where images, videos, pdf and other related files can be uploaded.

Just like instagram where you can upload your file with Just one field, please I really need the solution please

I’ve tried using filefield, but the image tag in HTML keep giving me an error, image field has no attribute file

Comment: Paste your code, it's easier to assist that way.

Answer (score 0):

First determine what error you get in html!  Read this section again in the Django documentation.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/http/file-uploads/